# Evaluate $\int{\mathrm{tr}}\left( {AB(I-xB)^{-1}}\right) {\,dx}$ for $A$ and $B$ square real matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, trace

Let $A$ and $B$ be two real $n\times n$ matrices, and let $C(x)=B(I-xB)^{-1}$,
where $I$ is the identity matrix of order $n$, for any real scalar $x$ such that $I-xB$ is invertible. Denote by $\mathrm{tr}$ the trace operator.

Is it possible to get a closed form solution for

$$\int{\mathrm{tr}}\left(  {AC(x)}\right)   {\,dx},$$

at least when $B$ is diagonalizable?

---

What I've done so far:

Assuming $B$ is diagonalizable, $C$ is too, and hence
it admits the spectral decomposition

$$
C(x)=\sum_{\lambda\in\mathrm{Sp}(B)}\frac{\lambda}{1-x\lambda}Q_{\lambda},
$$

where $\mathrm{Sp}(B)$ denotes the set of distinct eigenvalues of $B$, and
$Q_{\lambda}$ is the projector onto $\mathrm{null}(B-\lambda I)$ along
$\mathrm{col}(B-\lambda I)$ ($\mathrm{null}$ and $\mathrm{col}$ stand for the null and the column spaces). Hence

$$
\int{\mathrm{tr}}\left(  {AC(x)}\right)  {\,dx}=\sum_{\lambda\in
\mathrm{Sp}(B)}\mathrm{tr}(AQ_{\lambda})\int\frac{\lambda}{1-x\lambda}\,dx
$$

If all the eigenvalues of $B$ are real we obtain

$$
\int{\mathrm{tr}}\left(  {AC(x)}\right)  {\,dx}=\sum_{\lambda\in
\mathrm{Sp}(B)}\mathrm{tr}(AQ_{\lambda})\int\frac{\lambda}{1-x\lambda
}\,dx=\sum_{\lambda\in\mathrm{Sp}(B)}\mathrm{ln}(\left\vert 1-x\lambda
\right\vert )\mathrm{tr}(AQ_{\lambda})
$$

But what about the case in which not all eigenvalues of $B$ are real? Do we
get any simplification from the fact that the eigenvalues of real matrices
come in complex conjugate pairs, and the eigenvectors (and hence the
projectors $Q_{\lambda}$) associated to complex conjugate eigenvalues are
complex conjugates? Can we still use the formula in the last display above for $\int{\mathrm{tr}}\left(  {AC(x)}\right)  {\,dx}$?

Comment: Why is there an $x$ remaining after you have worked out the integral? It *is* meant to be a definite integral, right? But then what is the domain of integration?

Comment: It is meant to be an indefinite integral. Is there anything unclear in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f:x\in I\subset \mathbb{R}\rightarrow -tr(A\log(I-xB)),g(x)=\log(I-xB)$. We assume that $\log(.)$ is the principal log.; thus we assume that, for every eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $B$ and $x\in I$, $1-x\lambda\notin (-\infty,0]$.

When $x$ is small, $g(x)=-xB-(xB)^2/2-(xB)^3/3-\cdots$ and $g'(x)=-B(I+xB+(xB)^2+(xB)^3+\cdots)=-B(I-xB)^{-1}$. By extending the equalities between holomorphic functions, $g'(x)=-B(I-xB)^{-1}$ is valid for any $x\in I$.

Now $f'(x)=-tr(Ag'(x))=tr(AB(I-xB)^{-1})$ and we are done.

EDIT. Answer to mark. 1. $g'(x)$ and $-B(I-xB)^{-1}$ are analytic functions; there are equal in a neighborhood of $0$; then they are equal on whole domain of definition -if it is connected-.

2. The set $E=\{1-x\lambda; x\in I,\lambda\in sp(B)\}$ is included in $n$ straight lines going through $1$. Then, there is a half line $D$ from $0$ that does not intersect $E$. Finally, choose the $\log(.)$ associated to $D$. It remains the conditions $1-x\lambda\not= 0$.

Comment: Many thanks for this, very useful indeed. I think I need some help to understand completely though. 
(i) From your second paragraph, I can see $g'(x)=-B(I-xB)^{-1}$ for small $x$. What is the argument needed to show this actually holds for any $x\in I$? (ii) What can be done when $x\in I$ and $1-x\lambda\in (-\infty,0]$? Can a solution for the integral still be given?

Comment: thanks so much for the edit, I feel privileged that you’re explaining this to me. Concerning your answer 1, I can now see that $g'(x)=-B(I-xB)^{-1}$ over any interval containing an interval where the series for $g(x)$ and $g'(x)$ converge. But now suppose the domain $I$ is $(0,b)\cup(b,c)$, where $b\neq0$ is the reciprocal of a real eigenvalue of $B$ ($I-xB$ is singular at $x=b$), and $c$ is some real scalar greater than $b$. Can I show $g'(x)=-B(I-xB)^{-1}$ over a disconnected set $I$ of this type? This must be true, mustn't it?

Comment: We consider the $\log(.)$ associated to the half line $D$ (that is not parallel to $Ox$). Then the condition associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda=1/b>0$ is $x\notin \Delta$ a half line from $b$ that is parallel to $D$ (here $x$ is seen as a complex number). $g'(x)=-B(I-xB)^{-1}$ is valid for small complex numbers $x$. Since $\mathbb{C}\setminus  \Delta$ is connected, the equality is valid in whole the previous set and in particular on $(0,b)\cup (b,c)$.

Comment: There's one thing I still don't understand. We know that the solution $f(x)$
to my question must be real, because it's the integral of a real function. I can see that your proposed
solution $f(x)=-\mathrm{tr}(A\log(I-xB))$ works for $x$ such that no
eigenvalues of $I-xB$ are in $(-\infty,0]$. In that case we take $\log$ to be
the principal log, and hence we know $\log(I-xB)$ is real (because the
principal log of a real matrix is real). But what happens when $I-xB$ has
eigenvalues in $(-\infty,0]$ so that we need a non-principal branch of the
matrix log? How can we guarantee $f(x)$ is real?

Comment: @ mark , the indefinite integral is not real (there is the constant $i\pi$); yet, the definite integral $\int_a^b(.)dx$ is real.

Comment: 1/2 Many thanks once again, your comments are very helpful. I want to make sure I understand correctly. If I do, a real explicit
expression for $\int\mathrm{tr}\left(  {A({I-x}A)^{-1}}\right)  {\,dx}$,
holding for any $x$ such that ${{I-x}A}$ is invertible, is given by the real
part of $\mathrm{tr}\left(  {\log}(I-xA)\right)$ (plus real constant), where $\log$ denotes the
logarithm associated to $D$ ($D$ is a ray in $\mathbb{C}$ from the origin that
does not intersect the set $E:=\left\{  1-x\lambda:\text{ }x\in\mathbb{R}
\text{, }\lambda\in \mathrm{Sp}(A)\right\}  $).

Comment: 2/2 In this case, in which I have dropped
the matrix $B$, the solution $\mathrm{Re}\left(\mathrm{tr}\left(  {\log}(I-xA)\right)\right)$ can be expressed in terms of the real scalar log,
because $\mathrm{tr}\left(  {\log}(I-xA)\right)  ={\log}(\det(I-xA))$ and
hence $\mathrm{Re}\left(\mathrm{tr}\left(  {\log}(I-xA)\right)\right)={\log
}(\left\vert \det(I-xA)\right\vert )$, the vertical bars denoting the absolute
value (note $\det(I-xA)$ is real). Is this all correct?

Comment: @ mark . 1) A solution is $-tr(\log(I-xA))$. 2) $tr(\log(I-xA)=\log(\det(I-xA))$ is false. (Have a look when several eigenvalues of $I-xA$ are $<0$).  3) I think that, if $A$ is real, then a primitive has the form $\log(|\det(I-xA)|)$; yet beware, $x$ must go through a real SEGMENT where the conditions $1-x\lambda\not=0$ are always satisfied.

Comment: I wanted to write $-\log(|\det(I-xA)|)$.

Comment: I'm really thankful for your comments, they are incredibly helpful to me. To summarize, if I may, I'm looking for a real antiderivative of $\mathrm{tr}\left(  {A({I-x}A)^{-1}}\right)$, where $A$ is a real matrix and $x$ is a real scalar such that $I-xA$ is invertible. A real antiderivative is $-\mathrm{Re}\left(\mathrm{tr}\left(  {\log}(I-xA)\right)\right)=-{\log
}(\left\vert \det(I-xA)\right\vert )$. I did not understand your "beware" though? Isn't that condition satisfied for any $x$?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.